# Oracle SQL - Table created cannot be seen

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have never ever worked with Oracle before so please stay with me :)
I just want to do something simple : create a database and then create a table.
I am using oracle 18c version.
Ok so I have run the database configuration tool and my DB DB18c was successfully created. I then opened SQL Developer and created a new connection to this DB called localDB.
I created a new user RTT for this connection with admin privileges for everything.

Now I want to create a table calling a command; I created a file CreateAll.bat which contains the cmd:

```
sqlplus %USER%/%PWD%@%DB_NAME% @./tables/ulds.Table.sql
spool %LOG_FILE%
```

When I run it, I pass as arguments of my command the username/pwd I created and for the DB_NAME I enter DB18c.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Feb 21 09:15:30 2019
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I go back to SQL developer and refresh the tables under my user RTT however there is no table at all.
So my command is successfully completed but I dont know where my table was created? There is no filter apply to my Tables.
I dont know if I need to specify my connection name (localDB) somewhere in my command?

Below are the details extracted from the tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_DB18C =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MCMELM01.eur.ad.sag)(PORT = 1525))

DB18C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MCMELM01.eur.ad.sag)(PORT = 1525))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db18c)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Maybe with SQLPlus you connected to a different PDB (e.g. CDB$ROOT) than in SQL Developer

Comment: The PL/SQL was succeesfully competed but you do not konw if the table was created. I recommed you to start with a simpler command, just a create table directly from sqlplus and check if you can see it. This will narrow down possible causes of the problem.

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst that was it! thanks!!

Comment: you could also query the dba_tables view (assuming you have/can grant the privileges to see dba* views to your user) to see if the table exists anywhere in the database.